# How in Block a productcollection of template render?

Tags: magento2, products, renderer

How in Block

> app/code/Name/Name/Block/Rewrite/TopMyMenu.php

a productcollection of template

> "vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml"

render?

```
$productCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
              ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
              ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());
```

> $html = $produCtcollection->toHtml(); ?????

Comment: A product collection is just data, there is nothing to render. What are you trying to do? Display a product list like in category and search results?

Comment: Display a product list like in category

Answer (score 0):

`toHtml()` return block's html output

**Process**

\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php

```
    public function toHtml()
    {
/* dode */
            $this->_beforeToHtml();
            $html = $this->_toHtml();
            $this->_saveCache($html);
/* dode */
        return $html;
    }
```

Next this goes to 
\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
        return '';
    }
    return $this->fetchView($this->getTemplateFile());
}
```

Renders block html. and `$this->fetchView` function retrieves the block view from file (template).

Assume you know templates are using block functions and blocks extends core classes ( Template.php or AbstractBlock.php not in all cases ).

The data is populating by using toHtml()

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I asked wrong...
This solution I was looking for:

```
...
getBlockProductsHtml($productCollection);
...

 public function getBlockProductsHtml($collection) {
   $html = '';
   $html = $this->_layout
        ->createBlock('Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList')
        ->setTemplate('Namespace_Module::html/products-grid.phtml')
        ->setData('product_collection', $collection)
        ->toHtml();
    return $html;
 }
```

or

```
->setTemplate('Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml')
```

thanks to all